# Every sequence is composed of isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset M$ be a sequence. Prove that $$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\quad\exists \varepsilon> 0 \;B(x_n,\varepsilon)\cap \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \{x_n\}$$

Any hint? I don't know how to start this proof. Maybe reductio ad absurdum? Counterexamples?

Comment: What exactly is $A$?

Comment: Corrected, thanks

Comment: What if $M=\mathbb R$ with standard metric and the sequence is an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Hint:Consider a sequence that limits to a certain value and then add that value as the first term of the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sequence
$$ x_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{k} & n=2k \\ 0 & n=2k+1 \end{cases}$$

The idea is that if $x_n \to \ell$ and there exists $k$ such that $x_k=\ell$ then the property you say is definitely false.

Answer (score 0):

This is not generally true.

If the sequence is constant or finally constant your claim is true and follows easily.

If this sequence is non constant for $n\ge N$ then

1) $x_n\nrightarrow x_N$. Thus,
$$\exists \epsilon>0\forall k\in \mathbb{N}\ n\ge k\Rightarrow \left|x_n-x_N\right|>\epsilon$$
and...

2)$x_n\to x_N$. Then you can't continue. Such sequences exist as pointed out by Beni Bogosel.

Comment: If the sequence is constant or finally constant then on the contrary, the claim is true. In the first case $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{x_{n}\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and on the latter case $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a finite set.

Comment: @ThomasE. That's what I meant by "follows easily"

Comment: Now after the edit I see what you meant. It seemed first that the proposition being generally not true follows easily by considering a sequence that is constant or finally constant. Thanks for clarifying it.